# Unexpected difference in posted encodings between WAMP and LAMP php environments (Â detected)

Tags: php, apache, character-encoding

I have [mostly] successfully migrated away from a WAMP PHP environment onto a LAMP environment and all works fine, except I've spotted that when I post special characters to the php, then on the WAMP I get the posted results, but on the LAMP I get a scattering of Â characters in my results).

I have a simple php demonstrator page as follows:

```
<?php

echo "<html>";
echo "<head>";
echo "<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />";
echo "</head>";
echo "<body>";

$testcol="test2";
if ( isset($_POST[$testcol])) {
    //echo "<LI>".str_replace("[", "<BR>[",print_r(getallheaders(), true));
    echo "<LI>".getallheaders()['Content-Type'];
    echo "<LI> POST Encoding = ".mb_detect_encoding($_POST[$testcol], 'UTF-8', true);
    echo "<LI> _POST   = ".htmlentities($_POST[$testcol], ENT_QUOTES)."<HR>";

    $fn=ini_get('error_log').'.encoding_test.txt';
    file_put_contents($fn, $_POST[$testcol]);

    echo "Result stored in $fn<HR>";
}

$test="\"<lOR+EMØ>&"."'£$"."¥©Ȏ4$"."€";

echo "<LI>adjusted=".htmlspecialchars($test, ENT_QUOTES)."<BR>";

echo "<HR>";

echo "
<form method='post' action='" . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] . "'>
    
    <input type='text' name='test1' value='".addslashes($test)."'>
    <textarea name='test2'>$test</textarea>
    <input type='submit' value='Submit'>
    
</form>";

echo "</body>";
echo "</html>";
?>
```

When I run this, and click on the [Submit] button, on the WAMP environment** - and then look at the encoding_test.txt file I see:

```
"<lOR+EMØ>&'£$¥©Ȏ4$€
```

but when I run it on the LAMP, and look at the encoding_test.txt file, I see:

```
"<lOR+EMÃ>&'Â£$Â¥Â©È4$â¬
```

Why would this be? Is there a server setting or something I'm missing?

Thanks
Abe

** Note, on the browser - things all look the same between WAMP and LAMP - it's only on the server side that I see a difference

PS. Both runs show "POST Encoding = UTF-8"
PPS. I'm running on Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) PHP/7.0.33 and have compared the php.ini file and the Apache Server Information (via "SetHandler server-info"), between a working LAMP and my own LAMP and the results show no obvious differences (other than things like folder/filenames)

Comment: on checking other environments (WAMPS and LAMPS), I've found a mixture of results. No clear pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the only way I've been able to manage this discrepancy was to re-encode the result before using it,

```
$fn=ini_get('error_log').'.encoding_test2.txt';
$v=$_POST[$testcol];
$v=htmlentities($v, ENT_QUOTES);
$v=mb_convert_encoding($v, "HTML-ENTITIES","UTF-8");
$v=str_replace('"', "&quot;", $v);
$v=str_replace("'", "&apos;", $v);
$v=str_replace("&#039;", "&apos;", $v);
file_put_contents($fn, $v);
```

THAT SAID - I DID FIND THE UNDERLYING PROBLEM:
I was using Putty to read the LAMP files, and Notepad++ to read the WAMP files; but  it turned out that Putty was the problem - under the Putty Configuration options - my Window-Translation setting for "Received data assumed to be in which character set:" was set to "ISO-8859-1..." changing it to "UTF-8" solved the problem.